# Auto fill calculated value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Its been two days that I'm improving my code. This code is doing fine yet this time I want the third field or any last remaining field automatically fill-in with the remaining points. I'm trying to manipulate but it will just result to negative. I don't have the capability to calculate the exact values when I change values multiple times. Any help is much appreciated.Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading"> Please enter the weighted measurements for the criteria in selecting the scholars :</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
          <label class="control-label">
            Total criteria :
          </label>
          {!! Form::text('point','100',['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'remaining','disabled']) !!}
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">

            <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
              <label class="control-label">
                Percent for age: 
              </label>
              {!! Form::text('scholarship_points_one',null,['class'=>'form-control point','id'=>'f1','maxlength' => '3', 'min'=>'4', 'max'=>'100','placeholder'=>'Enter Your Rate 1 - 100']) !!}
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
              <label class="control-label">
               Percent for GPA: 
             </label>
             {!! Form::text('scholarship_points_two',null,['class'=>'form-control point','id'=>'f2','maxlength' => '3', 'min'=>'4', 'max'=>'100','placeholder'=>'Enter Your Rate 1 - 100']) !!}
           </div>

           <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
            <label class="control-label">
             Percent for location: 
           </label>
           {!! Form::text('scholarship_points_three',null,['class'=>'form-control point','id'=>'f3','maxlength' => '3', 'min'=>'4', 'max'=>'100','placeholder'=>'Enter Your Rate 1 - 100']) !!}
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var points = document.getElementsByClassName('point');
  var remaining = document.getElementById('remaining');
  for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    points[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      var inputPoints = getInputPoints();
      remaining.value = 100 - inputPoints;
    });
  }
  function getInputPoints() {
    var inputPoints = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
      if (!isNaN(points[j].value) && points[j].value != "") { inputPoints += parseInt(points[j].value);}
    }
    return inputPoints;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class `input-fields-to-sum` to your source input fields, then

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   calculateTotals();

    $(".input-fields-to-sum").on('input', function() {
        calculateTotals();
    });
});

function calculateTotals() {
   // walk on input fields with class, calculate sum and put it in total field
   // input can contain invalid numbers, handle errors when parsing
}

function parseNumber(str, defaultValue) {
    if (str !== undefined && str.length) {
        var parsed = parseFloat(str.replace(',','.').replace(/\s/g,'').replace(/\&nbsp\;/g,''));
        if (isNaN(parsed)) return defaultValue;
        return parsed;
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sir,I will try applying this logic and see if I have further question.

Comment: Sir, the problem here is the possibility that the user will input first in any field.So I cant put a fixed total field.